# Save image in the device gallery using Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Hello I should save images on the device when the user clicks the download button.
I'm using the cordova file transfer plugin, but I can not save images in the device gallery.

```
$("#downloadFile").click(function()
{
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("www.mysite.com/image.jpg");
    var fileURL =  cordova.file.????;

    fileTransfer.download(

    uri, fileURL, function(entry) 
    {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) 
    {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("download error code" + error.code);
    },
    false, 
    {
        headers: 
        {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    });
});
```

Are there any other ways to save an image using cordova?
Thanks, ciao

Comment: try the custom plugin to save image to device https://github.com/quiply/SaveImage

Comment: thanks for the comment.
I need to download from remote website ... the plugin uses the native path

Comment: you can write own plugin instead you don't need it

Comment: When you download the image you have the native url where it has been saved, so you can use that url to save it to the gallery, just use that plugin where you have the `alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-save-image

You should use this plugin

```
function(entry){
window.cordova.plugins.imagesaver.saveImageToGallery(uri, function(success){}, function(error){});
}
```

nativePathToJpegImage is uri.